# How to filter null or empty attributes from an Active Directory Query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am working with a customers Active Directory which has a lot of cruft in it. There are hundreds of Users with empty givenName and sn attributes. I would like to filter any records that have an empty sn or an empty givenName from my query results as those records cannot be processed by my application.

This works as per my requirements but I believe there must be a better way to do it:

```
(&(objectClass=User)(|(!(!(sn=*))))(!(!(givenName=*)))))
```

Is there a more clear and concise way to accomplish this with an ldap query?

Answer (score 2):

`sn` and `givenName` have as their superior the `name` attribute, which is of `DirectoryString` syntax, that is, the syntax is `1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15`. Attributes which are of syntax `DirectoryString` are not allowed to be null, that is, a `DirectoryString`  is required to have at least one character.

The filter `sn=*` is a `present` filter (not a substring or regular expression), meaning that the entry would be filtered out of the possible search results if the `sn` attribute is not present (if it is present, it must have at least one character). Same for `givenName=*`.

A simpler filter might be `'(&)'`, where the search request contains the following in its list of attributes to be returned: `@User`, which will return all attributes in the `User` objectClass for each entry that matches the filter, then have the application extract the `sn` and `givenName` attributes from each entry that is returned. If the number of entries returned is large, use the Simple Paged Results Request Control to throttle the number of entries returned to a more manageable value.

Or ... it might be that Active Directory is not LDAP compliant and does not support the `inetOrgPerson` objectClass and syntaxes of attributes therein correctly and *does* allow empty or `null` attributes values for `DirectoryString` attributes, though I can't imagine Microsoft would deliver a product that is not LDAP compliant.

#### see also

- [LDAP Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [RFC 4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519)

Answer (score 0):

(!(!(givenName=*))) = (!givenName=*)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198810.aspx